# How to add Background Image in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I've tried adding a background image in CSS and HTML but what I'm doing isn't working. The code I have currently is:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<style>
h1 {
color: #FFFFFF
}
body {
// I think it would go here
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `background-image` tag. Use `min-height: 100%;` to make the image fit the entire page.

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<style>
h1 {
color: #FFFFFF
}

body {
min-height: 100%;
background-image: url(/*The link goes here*/);
}

</style>
```

Comment: Instead of height use min-height: 100vh;

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `background` property with a `url` value.

```css
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

body {
  background: url('//placehold.it/200');
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
h1 {
color: #FFFFFF
}
body {
   background-image: url("http://www.readersdigest.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/4-ways-cheer-up-depressed-cat.jpg");
    
}
</style>
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```